# Generate GUID for header (X-Correlation-ConversationID) in wso2

Tags: http, header, wso2, endpoint, wso2-micro-integrator

Hi guys can anyone please guide me how can I generate a guid for sending it in header before calling an endpoint. I am working in wso2 MI 7.2 Is the below line correct ? or what can be changed ?

```
<property name="X-Correlation-ConversationID" expression="uuid()" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
```

Incase it should be done some other way please do let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try use `get-property('MessageID')` exprssion.

```
<property name="X-Correlation-ConversationID" expression="get-property('MessageID')" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
```

or extract only UUID using xpath substring function:

```
<property name="X-Correlation-ConversationID" expression="substring(get-property('MessageID'),10,36)" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: but what is MessageID here ?

Comment: WSO2 Generates ID for each msg that will processing in sequence. Every request will have different MessageID. Also if you have out sequence, that ID will be different.